# How to configure two monitors, one for GUI, the other for console

Tags: tty, multi-monitor

My Linux machine have both HDMI and VGA ports working, which can connect to two different monitors respectively.
Is it possible to configure the Linux so that one monitor shows the normal GUI, while the other shows the text-mode console, say tty3 (Ctrl+Alt+F3)?
The OS is 20.04.1-Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to configure your Linux machine to display the GUI on one monitor and a text-mode console on another. 
Here's a breakdown of the methods and considerations:

Methods:

Multiseat Configuration: This is the most flexible but potentially complex solution, especially if you don't have experience in multiseat setups. It allows you to have multiple independent "seats" (users), each with their own keyboard, mouse, and monitor(s).

You can then configure one seat to be a GUI desktop and another to be a text-mode console.

Search terms: "Linux multiseat configuration", "Linux multiseat Xorg"

Using `con2fb`: This method uses the 'con2fb' utility to redirect a specific virtual console (like tty3) to a different framebuffer. 
This is less complex than a full multiseat setup.

Install con2fb: Use your distribution's package manager
(e.g., `sudo apt yum xbps install con2fb` for Debian/Ubuntu).

Locate your framebuffers:
Usually `/dev/fb0` is your primary display, and `/dev/fb1` is secondary. 
Redirect the console: For example,
to move tty3 to the second framebuffer:

```
sudo con2fb /dev/fb1 /dev/tty3
```

Kernel Mode Setting (KMS) and Early KMS Configuration: This involves modifying your boot parameters to configure how the Linux kernel initializes graphics. 
It offers more granular control but requires deeper understanding of KMS.

There are tools, like KMSCon, to assist with this.

Considerations:

- Graphics card: Ensure your graphics card supports driving multiple independent displays. Most modern ones do.
- Distributions and display managers: Specific steps might differ slightly based on your Linux distribution and the display manager in use (GDM, LightDM, etc.).
- Permanence: For non-permanent changes, con2fb is convenient. To make changes persist across reboots, you'll likely need to modify boot arguments or display manager configuration, depending on your chosen method.

Additional Tips:

- Consult your Linux distribution's documentation for detailed guidance.
- Experiment with non-critical machines first to avoid disrupting your primary work environment.

If you run into specific issues, search online
based on your Linux distribution, graphics card,
and chosen method, along with any error messages.